# Admin site registering models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have those models

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)

class B(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    relation = ForeignKey(A)
```

And I can register like this:

```
admin.site.register(A)
admin.site.register(B)
```

In `/admin/` page, I can see A and B registered.
and "Add B" admin page, will display a combo with (+) icon to add a new "A".
What I want is only register "B" and keep the (+) icon, the problem is: if "A" is not  registered this icon dissapears of this place :( so and I cant add "A" when adding "B"s

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`relation = ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)` will let you save a B without needing to link it to an A. Does that help?